# How can you add a Microsoft Graph client service as a MediatR service in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, mediator, mediatr

So I have a .NET Core web API with it's own local data context, and I'd like to add the ability to call Microsoft Graph as a downstream API.

However, when I try to add the necessary properties to call the Graph API, I get a build error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.Users.Me+Query,Microsoft.Graph.User] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Application.Users.Me+Handler': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient' while attempting to activate 'Application.Users.Me+Handler'.)
```

Here is my startup class:

```
using API.Middleware;
using Application.TestEntities;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Persistence;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
            services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                });
            });

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
            services.AddControllers(opt =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Create>());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And my application handler for calling downstream:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace Application.Users
{
    public class Me
    {
        public class Query : IRequest<User> { }

        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Query, User>
        {
            private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
            private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
            public Handler(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
            {
                _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
                _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
            }

            public async Task<User> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
                return user;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully I'm on the right track here, but please let me know if I'm not.

Comment: Hope you're using the latest NuGet packages for the above SDKs, right?

Comment: I believe yes, for the most part..

For my API project (startup) I have:

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - 3.1.10
Newtonsoft.Json - 12.0.3
Microsoft.Identity.Web - 1.3.0`

For Application I have:

`MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection - 8.1.0
FluentValidation.AspNetCore - 9.2.0
Microsoft.Graph - 3.20.0
Microsoft.Identity.Web - 1.3.0`

Comment: Just upgraded all of my packages, and got rid of Newtonsoft.Json as I am not using it any longer.
Issue persists.

Comment: Good that you tried. As a next steps i would start isolating the packages one-by-one and adding back to see, compile to see at which point i see the error. This will help you to eliminate the issues with the libraries that you use. In addition i would see any reference documents talking about the exact combo to see if any know issue is reported as well.

Comment: Do you know what the error means that I'm getting?

Comment: I remember a related thread where they had the same error @ https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11232

Comment: you have registered the handler with the dependency injection container but not the GraphServiceClient, so when the dependency injection container tries to build your handler via it's consctructor, it doesn't know how to construct an instance of GraphServiceClient

Comment: @franklores Thank you - I think that's what I was forgetting. So I added Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph to my API project and added it as a service. The build error went away.
I'll need to configure it further, but once I get it all pieced together I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right so this was a simple oversight on my part.

As per @franklores, you need to register Microsoft Graph in your startup class services:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Adding the following to appsettings (scopes may differ):

```
  "DownstreamAPI": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
```

And be sure to install `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph` to enable the `AddMicrosoftGraph()` function.